# Recurring Job was skipped on a single day, no explanation why

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have been using Hangfire for several years now. Recently I have had an issue with a recurring job, where there was a single day that was skipped. The job that was skipped, continued to run the next day without any intervention or changes to the job itself, and any other supporting infrastructure (webserver/IIS, database etc).

I have extensive logs that capture all actions during the job itself, for example job startup, if job is allowed to execute the function in the job (basically an on/off switch), if job has run, if job had any errors/exceptions.
Basically the 1st log entry for the job is logged regardless of the on/off switch, so even if the switch was set to disabled, the job still would have fired and created a log entry.
In this case I am not seeing any entries at all.
For all other jobs that were triggered there are logs available, for the skipped job there is no indication it ever started.

In addition to this issue, I am also having some trouble obtaining the correct date in order to perform an action inside the job. I am using DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours() to obtain my local time inside the job. We are using several other logging timestamps for other operations, therefore I am certain that it does not have to do with clock / timezone changes.

Any thoughts or similar experiences regarding these issues?

Elbert

Comment: _I have been using Hangfire for several years now. Recently I have had an issue with a recurring job, where there was a single day that was skipped_: Did someone die as a result of this? If not, I wouldn't worry about a single occurrence too much.

Comment: How do you schedule it? _Could_ it have been due to daylight savings - switching? I don't know about HangFire but I am pretty sure Quartz.NET recommends to not schedule into daylight savings - relevant times. For anything that forces me to work with local / zoned dates and time I use Noda.

Comment: We are using the hangfire jobscheduler for sending out email/sms notices where we need to have the job at least start.  We want to have a clear indication as to what went wrong.

Comment: As for the scheduling, the app has the AddOrUpdate() command included when the app starts, which rechecks if the job needs to be recreated.  The job executes daily. We are currently not using daylight savings time, the recurring job scheduling is using UTC - 4.

Comment: _We want to have a clear indication as to what went wrong_: Hire an IT professional - this is what their paid to do. If you are the IT professional and don't possess the necessary skills, you may consider hiring a consultant. You may also consider submiting a support ticket to the product that you're using: _Hangfire_.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Hangfire issue tracker? There are many results if you search for "skip". Like [this one](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1118), and [this one](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/899), and many others with hints on things you want to look at, mostly to do with IIS recycling itself.